# Can't move 'logout' button to the right

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-5, nav, right-align

After several hours of research and variout attempts, I cannot seem to workout how to move this Logout button from within my Navbar to the very right of the screen.

I have tried every example I can find online, creating a new nav bar, setting the float to right, text align to the right, etc.

Please find the attached HTML/Django:

navbar.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light p-0">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav" style="height: 4rem;">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'signed in' %}">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'add meal' %}">Add Meal</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'view private profile' %}">View Private Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'view food log' %}">Food Log</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'view friends' %}">Friends</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'settings' %}">Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" style="float: right">
                <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'logout' %}" style="background-color: #e85c29">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you used your browsers dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what css is being applied to that element  and who is applying it?

Comment: @AHaworth hello, yes I have and unfortunately I still cannot identify why it is doing this.

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible to fix this without seeing a snippet which includes the relevant CSS. How is the width of the navbar  set for example? If that isn’t 100vw then your last item will only go to the right of whatever width the navbar is whatever you position it with unless you take it out of the navbar sequence.

Comment: @AHaworth it was all done using Bootstrap so there isn't any written CSS on my end.

Comment: Have a look to what is being set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the logout link is enclosed within the `div` tag in your navbar. Try moving it outside the div block.

```
<nav style="background-color: green;" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light p-0">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" width="100%" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav" style="height: 4rem;">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'signed in' %}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'add meal' %}">Add Meal</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'view private profile' %}">View Private Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'view food log' %}">Food Log</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'view friends' %}">Friends</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'settings' %}">Settings</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="nav-item mr-3 nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'logout' %}" style="background-color: #e85c29">Logout</a>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<li class="nav-item" style="float: right">
                <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'logout' %}" style="background-color: #e85c29">Logout</a>
</li>
```

to this

```
<li class="nav-item" style="float: right; width: 100%;">
                <a class="nav-link p-3" href="{% url 'logout' %}" style="background-color: #e85c29">Logout</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi @Mohamed, unfortunately this did not solve the problem.